.net Maui headphone doesn't switch after application is running
I've got my .net Maui Application working with a bluetooth headset as long as the user connects the bluetooth headset prior to running the application.
If the user forgets to connect the headset and starts the application then tries to connect the headset, it will show its connected on the iPad but the sound will not route to/from the headset.  The iPad Speaker and built-in microphone are in control.
Does anyone know what is going on?
I assume it has to do with setting the audio session.  This code is run at application start.  If this is what I need to run after the application is running, how would I detect the headphones are connected?
public bool SetAudioSession()
{

    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
    var err = audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth |
                                        AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowAirPlay | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker);

    if (err != null)
        return false;

    err = audioSession.SetActive(true);

    if (err != null)
        return false;

    return true;


}


You've already set up the AudioSession() method in your code, if you set the breakpoint at var err = audioSession.SetCategory(), when opening the app and connecting headphone, what is the value of err?

The headphones work when the application starts.  It's when I turn on the headphones after the application is already running.  The application won't start using the headphones.

I understand your problem. Please try set the breakpoint at var err = audioSession.SetCategory(), then open the app and then connect the Bluetooth headset. What is the value of err at this time?

there is no error...  I should have said that prior.  err = null when the headset is not connected.

Does this problem also occur on the Android platform? Also, what is your iOS version? Will this problem also occur in other iOS versions?

Only on iOS at the moment, not working on Android until apple is complete.  Only have one iPad to test on, it's a 10th generation iPAD running iOS 17.4.1.  I have no way of testing on other devices.

Have you overridden the Stopped method in your project, you can refer to the
Cross-platform lifecycle events
